# AEM Form: Change access control of textfield

Tags: javascript, aem

I'm using Adobe AEM Form, javascript for scripting.

In my form, I have a drop down which allow the user to pick one of the dropdown value item or to fill the textfield by typing. My script as follows:

```
Report.Page2.part2.body.subform.Dropdown::exit - (JavaScript, client)
if(this.selectedIndex == "0"){
    Textfield.access = "???????"
    Textfield.fillColor = "255,255,255"

}
else{
    Textfield.rawValue = this.rawValue;
    Textfield.access = "readOnly"
    Textfield.fillColor = "192,192,192"
}
```

I am able to change the Textfield to read only, but not able to change it back to writtable. Can someone advice me how to? and other than "readOnly", what other access control can I assign to the textfield.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `Textfield.access = ""`?

Comment: I just did and it works! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already an accepted answer so just adding a few details on why it works the way it works as suggested in my comments.

```
TextField.access="literal";
```

will generate a markup as below

```
<input type="xxx" literal>
</input>
```

There are some validations in the framework to check for the allowed values so the literal won't break the HTML over here. The key issues is that this literal is not an attribute so it cannot have a value. For example, the following markup is not possible:

```
<input enabled="false"></input>
```

In order to clear the attribute, the only way you can reset it is by using an empty string as below:

```
TextField.access="";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Report.Page2.part2.body.subform.Dropdown::exit - (JavaScript, client)
if(this.selectedIndex == "0"){
    Textfield.access = ""
    Textfield.fillColor = "255,255,255"

}
else{
    Textfield.rawValue = this.rawValue;
    Textfield.access = "readOnly"
    Textfield.fillColor = "192,192,192"
}
```

Comment: Have to used another account to mark this as answered. Credit to dtr-java

Comment: You can actually use your own account to answer your question. SO doesn't frown upon it (mods correct me if I am wrong over here).